# Topics are not getting associated with forum

Tags: 8, nodes

I am testing out the Drupal 8 core Forum module.  I am using a theme that I based off of Acquia Lightning.  I have successfully installed the module and added Containers, Forums and Topics.  My issue is that the Topics I create don't seem to get associated with the Forum taxonomy.  In other words, when I go to /forum I see my containers and forums but every forum has Topics: 0, Posts: 0, Last Post: n/a.

I have tried clearing cache, running cron, looking at the watchdog logs but nothing seems to indicate why it isn't working.  I am not receiving any memory errors, white screen of death, etc.  All other site functions seem to work properly: I can save content and taxonomies, create new views, assign blocks, etc.

See the attached screen grab.  I could use some ideas on what might be causing this.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
drush state:set comment.maintain_entity_statistics TRUE
```

Explanation:

core/modules/comment/src/CommentStatistics.php in the update() function says this:

```
// Allow bulk updates and inserts to temporarily disable the maintenance of
// the {comment_entity_statistics} table.
if (!$this->state->get('comment.maintain_entity_statistics')) {
  return;
}
```

In my case, somehow this was not set, causing this function to bail out and not update the comment_entity_statistics table. Drupal needs this table updated to display the proper forum posts.

"drush state:get comment.maintain_entity_statistics" can be used to check if this is already set.

Comment: The *comment_entity_statistics* database table contains statistics about the comments. It's not used to count the number of posts a forum contains, since those are nodes, not comments. That table is used to show *new* close to a node title, to mean there was new activity on that node, for example a new comment.